# C# MVC - Access Items in a List that is in a Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a Blog that is populating from a BlogResponseModel, and the related comments for each Blog entry are held in a List.  It looks like this:

```
public class BlogResponseModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime SubmissionDate { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ImageID { get; set; }
    public string ImageAttribution { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public List<BlogCommentModel> CommentList { get; set; }
}
```

The comments are collected and each comment is related to the Id element above. The BlogCommentModel looks like this:

```
public class BlogCommentModel
{
    public int CommentId { get; set; }
    public int CommentCount { get; set; }
    public DateTime CommentDate { get; set; }
    public string Commenter { get; set; }
    public string CommenterEmail { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public int BlogParentId { get; set; }
}
```

In my view, I am using a foreach to format and display each Blog entry, and this is working very well.  Where I have hit the wall is figuring out how to embed the related comments at the foot of each Blog post.

Here is the current attempt in the View that has me stumped. I do a foreach to render the Blog post...

```
   @foreach (var response in Model)
   {
        // enter all the Blog specifics here...
```

At this point, the Blog entry is rendered, and we are ready to add the Comments:

```
<div class="message row">
    <div>
        <H5>Comments</H5>
    </div>
    @foreach (var comment in ?? WHAT ?? (how do I access BlogResponseModel)
    {
        <div class="replies span12">
            <div class="reply">
                <div class="created pull-right">
                    @comment.CommentDate
                </div>
                <div class="created">
                    @comment.Commenter
                </div>
                <div>
                    @comment.Comment
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

How do I populate the Comments from List CommentList that is in the BlogResponseModel?

Thanks in advance for your advice.  I'm new to MVC and still wrapping my mind around the architecture.

Comment: Is your view `@model IEnumerable<BlogResponseModel>`?

Comment: By looking at your `@foreach (var response in Model)` . I guess you can use `response.CommentList` in your second foreach.

Comment: Do you want to display the comments within the blog foreach loop or do you want to display it outside the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add

```
public virtual ICollection<BlogCommentModel> CommentList { get; set; }
```

instead of

```
public List<BlogCommentModel> CommentList { get; set; }
```

Then in the View

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)

    @foreach (var myBlogCommentModel in @item.BlogCommentModel)
    {
        @myBlogCommentModel.Commenter
        @myBlogCommentModel.CommenterEmail
    }
}
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: SWEET!!!  One update, in case anyone else has this same issue..  Modify the (at)foreach (var myBlogCommentModel in (at)item.BlogCommentModel) to read (at)foreach (var myBlogCommentModel in item.CommentList) and it works beautifully!!!